# schema file hosting ftp server

Tags: php, mysql, ftp, schema

I am interested in the structure of a file hosting services how to works with multiple server like see schema?

I don't know if it's possible?

[image]

Original size :[schema.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL2dw.jpg)

Schema:

- client upload a file (file.txt) on principal server

  - server check server space is reached and move to server#1
  - Upload file.txt to server#1 and
  - saving info in database with server#1/file.txt
  - return info links to client..

But in upload.php how to change ftp info for multiple server?

Of Course, this is my vision.

I don't know if it's really if file hosting works.

So if you think the idea is not good, thank you for sharing your knowledge?

Comment: Clean Graphics, What tool did you use ?

Comment: @Baba thanks, i'm using photoshop for schema because i prefer for simplicity and icon i use iconfinder website..

Comment: I would look into CDN solutions like the ones offered by Amazon or Rackspace

Comment: Try also the Softlayer CDN, quite interesting solution extremely easy to setup and works like a ftp too, and not that expansive like Amazon

Comment: This question is a joke ... upload.php ... just joke. -1 from me. And question is in wrong place. And it is ambiguous.

Comment: Interesting approach with HDFS thank you all for contribution and Ben for answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [HDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/hdfs_design.html#NameNode+and+DataNodes). This clustered filesystem (though mostly geared towards use cases when intensive computation is needed over large sets of data) seems close to what you're describing.

The way they solve the connection issue, is to have a custom service which acts similar to ftp (it supports commands like put and get) which allows you to connect to the cluster generically and it sorts out where to put it.